# How to remove some files from commit in git?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, version-control

I,by mistake ,added some files to staging area,and as well as commited it.I want to remove some files locally before pushing them.How can I do it?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is your last commit, just do:

`git reset --soft HEAD~1`

You will go down one commit. Then you can restore unwanted files for this commit, add mores or change commit messages.